# Why does my upgrade says it needs more space than what a clean installation needs?

Tags: system-installation, disk-management

I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop with the following disk organization:

- 20 GB for /
- 5 GB for /home

The large root I have was intended in principle for installing large pieces of scientific software, but in fact I don't have any of that software installed currently.
I have checked my disk space for installing ubuntu 12.04 and I have found that it takes ~15 GB. I have checked on the web that a typical installation should be ~4-6 GB.

How can it be? I don't have big pieces of software, I have also removed the Office Suite to have more space. I keep all my data somewhere else. My installation is pretty minimal. I have already removed all the old kernel and header files, cleaned with `apt-get autoremove` and removed any unused piece of software with `Computer Janitor`.

In fact I found 4.5GB of scientific software I had forgotten about, nonetheless the installation would be 10.5 GB without those pieces of software, that seems still a lot to me. I also have the full `tetex-latex` installed.

The upgrade to 12.04 require 5GB of space, and I had to remove 3.5GB of that optional software I had.

Now I have the following:

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8                  20G   15G  4.3G  78% /
udev                      993M  4.0K  993M   1% /dev
tmpfs                     401M  860K  400M   1% /run
none                      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                     1003M  7.0M  996M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6                 5.0G  4.1G  612M  88% /home
```

that 15GB still look like a lot, it is 3.5GB more than v10.04

---

output of `sudo du -hs --exclude=/proc /*`

```
8.6M    /bin
32M     /boot
0       /cdrom
460K    /core
4.0K    /dev
20M     /etc
0       /gl_driver.so
0       /initrd.img
176M    /lib
4.4M    /lib64
16K     /lost+found
32K     /media
458M    /opt
116K    /path
19M     /root
1.1M    /run
9.3M    /sbin
4.4G    /scratch
4.0K    /selinux
200K    /srv
0       /sys
104K    /tmp
6.6G    /usr
520M    /var
0       /vmlinuz
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `df -h` to your question just to provide some evidence. Check also how many kernels/headers you have installed - there are usually way too many, and removing all but last should free a lot of space. The command to do that is `dpkg -l | grep "ii   linux"`

Comment: all the unused kernels had been previously removed

Comment: So, apparently something takes up space. Can you add the output of `sudo du -hs --exclude=/proc /*` as well. ...almost forgot, have you tried `sudo apt-get clean`? That deletes all the cached installation packages.

Comment: The output above shows that the most space is taken by `4.4G    /scratch`, and `6.6G    /usr`. Everything else is pretty insignificant.

Comment: without the software that I have installed in `/opt` and `\scratch`, the total installation is `7.4GB`. is it typical?

Comment: Yes, it is. /usr tends to grow as you install stuff from the repositories. Check the installation history, in case you suspect something still needs to be removed.

Comment: Note to review: We should re-open this. It's about upgrading (the version is irrelevant), and it's an upgrade to a supported version.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the installer needs to download the updates packages first, which pretty much sums 3 times what you are using right now. Example:

You have 3 GB of programs installed, the packages to upgrade all that weights about 1.7 GB, now all those packages need to be uncompressed when installing, so you will be using 3 GB or more extra. The grand total 7.7 GB of data to do a full upgrade. That's why you need the extra space when upgrading from a release to another. In your case, since you have already `/home` in another partition, just install Ubuntu 12.04 on top of the root filesystem. Tell the installer that you want to use the old `/home` **without formating**, and you should be in 12.04 pretty quick.